# Angular problem to set an input to empty value

Tags: angular, input

I have a form with search bar and I would like to set the value of the bar to empty after a click on button Cancel or Save :

This is the input in my template :

```
 <div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchTxt"  id="filtrer" [value]="searchEmpty" (input) = "onSearchTrigger(searchTxt.value)" placeholder="Rechercher un organisme financeur" #searchTxt>
```

And the two buttons cancel and save in my template :

```
  <div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
            data-dismiss="modal" (click) ="onModalCancel()">Annuler</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSubmit()" data-dismiss="modal"
            [disabled]="!registrationForm.valid"> Valider</button></div>
      </div>
```

In my component, I have two functions :

```
  onSubmit() {
this.isSubmitted = true;
if (!this.registrationForm.valid) {
  return false;
  // tslint:disable-next-line: no-else-after-return
} else {
  this.myCodeOrganisme = this.registrationForm.value.orga;
  this.serviceHttp2.getAllOrganismes().subscribe(resp => (this.organismesFinanceurs = resp));
  for (const organisme of this.organismesFinanceurs) {
    if (organisme.code === this.myCodeOrganisme) {
      this.myLibelleOrganisme = organisme.libelleLong;
    }
  }
  this.isSubmitted = false;
  this.searchEmpty = '';
}
  }

  onModalCancel() {
this.searchEmpty = null;
  }
```

And the console returns me this error :

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.

So how can I set the input search bar to empty ??

Thank you

Comment: are you getting this error while click the button or on the initial page load

Comment: I have this error when clicking on the button

Comment: Why are you returning `false` in the `onSubmit` method? You can safely omit the `false` keyword as you're probably not using the return value anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the component properties not in the subscribe of the server response. You are looping through `this.organismesFinanceurs` and set new properties and afterwards the server response is updating `this.organismesFinanceurs`. Try to move this functionality in the subscribe of the Http Request (see below):

```
onSubmit() {
  this.isSubmitted = true;
  if (!this.registrationForm.valid) {
    return false;
    // tslint:disable-next-line: no-else-after-return
  } else {
    this.myCodeOrganisme = this.registrationForm.value.orga;
    this.serviceHttp2.getAllOrganismes().subscribe(resp => {
      this.organismesFinanceurs = resp;

      for (const organisme of this.organismesFinanceurs) {
        if (organisme.code === this.myCodeOrganisme) {
          this.myLibelleOrganisme = organisme.libelleLong;
        }
      }
      this.isSubmitted = false;
      this.searchEmpty = '';
    });
  }
}
```